# Insert multiple xml data files into tinkerpop graph database via gremlin server (with gremlin code)

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, gremlin-server

I have huge dataset that must be inserted into a graph database via gremlin (gremlin server). Becuase the xml file is too big (over 8gb in size), I decided to split it into multiple, manageable nine xml files (about 1gb each). My question is, is there a way to use the insert each of these data files into my tinkerpop graph database via gremlin server? i.e. trying something like this? or, what is the best way to insert these data please?

```
  graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph("data01.xml")
  graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph("data02.xml")
  graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph("data03.xml")
  graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph("data04.xml")
  graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph("data05.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a large GraphML file. I'm not sure I've ever come across one so large. I'd wonder how you went about splitting it since GraphML files aren't easily split as they are XML based, have a header and a structure where vertices and edges are in separate nodes. It was for these reasons (and others) that TinkerPop developed formats like Gryo and GraphSON which were easily split for processing in Hadoop-like file structures.

That said, assuming you split your GraphML files correctly so that each file was a complete subgraph I suppose that you would be able to load them the way you are suggesting, however, I'd be concerned about how much memory you'd need to do this. The `io()` loader is not mean for bulk parallel loading and basically holds an in-memory cache of vertices to speed loading. That in-memory cache is essentially just a `HashMap` that doesn't expire its contents. Therefore, while the loading is occurring you would need to be able to hold all of the `Vertex` instances in memory for a particular file.

I don't know what your requirements are or how you ended up with such a large GraphML file, but for a graph of this size I would look at either the provider specific bulk loading tools of the graph you are using or some custom method that used [spark-gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sparkgraphcomputer) or a Gremlin script of some sort to parallel load your data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just a few follow up questions, if I may please? Firstly, would it be easier to insert the data if I converted it to JSON or Gryo format? Secondly, I am quite new to the latter format, is there a way to write a java program to convert CSV data files to gryo format please? And finally, would I have memory issues if I tried to insert large data files (like the one mentioned in my question) via gremlin-OLAP (GraphComputer) or spark-gremlin? Thank you once again.

Comment: GraphSON might be easier than Gryo as it is JSON-based so as long as you follow the expected format you could use any JSON library to generate it technically. I don't think you should try to convert your graph to Gryo directly. I suppose that you could always run into memory problems no matter what loading tool you're using, but provider specific loaders and spark-gremlin are suited to this task so I'd not expect the same type of trouble I alluded to in my answer.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.